# How to Build a Custom wxPython Custom Menu Widget

Tags: python, user-interface, drop-down-menu, menu, wxpython

**Background:**

In recent days I've been experimenting with building many ordinary widgets from scratch in wxPython using the PyControl method of building custom controls as a personal challenge. However, I've hit issues when building a custom menu widget. By this I mean I am envisaging a button that when clicked on yields a drop down menu of options/commands etc.

**Question:**

What is the best way of achieving a completely custom menu widget in wxPython? Ideally I'd like to use only original code (i.e. as much as possible handled directly in the code). An ideal answer would include a runnable code snippet if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you mean this ? http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/Createpopupmenu.htm

Comment: Something like that, yes. Of course, I'm looking to make it from scratch rather than use existing tools if possible :)

Comment: just draw a panel and put clickable lables ... no idea why you would want to re-invent that particular wheel... thats like asking how to make a frame widget (it uses native OS specific controls for both tasks)

Comment: I realise it's a pointless task rebuilding an existing widget, but like I said, I'm using it as a challenge to get used to wxPython.

Comment: and yet then you ask for completely runnable code example? anyway ask and ye shall recieve

Comment: ehh it took too long to whip up an example ... maybe you will get lucky and someone else will ...

Comment: Take a look at the FlatMenu widget. It's a custom widget written in Python.